# Custom DataGridView adds columns every time I build

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I am writing an inherited `DataGridView` control which by default will have two columns. The DGV lives on a user control `GeneralTabPanel` which inherits from `MainTabPanel` which inherits from `UserControl`. Reason is `MainTabPanel` contains a virtual function that every inheriting panel must override.

The problem is whenever I look at the `GeneralTabPanel` in the Designer and I hit Build, **Visual Studio Express 2013** will generate two columns in the Designer and add them to the DGV.

**SuperDataGridView**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnyGameEngineEditor {

    public class SuperDataGridView : DataGridView {

        public SuperDataGridView () {
            this.ColumnCount = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**GeneralTabPanel**

```
namespace AnyGameEngineEditor {
    public partial class GeneralTabPanel : MainTabPanel {

        public GeneralTabPanel () {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

    }
}
```

**MainTabPanel**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnyGameEngineEditor {
    public partial class MainTabPanel : UserControl {
        public MainTabPanel () {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

    }
}
```

This is as barebones as I can get to reproducing the issue on my machine with VS2013 Express. This is how to reproduce (I have not actually tested this on another machine):

1. Make a new Windows Forms project.
2. Copy these three files into the root folder.
3. Open up `GeneralTabPanel` in the designer.
4. Open up the Designer .cs file for `GeneralTabPanel`.
5. Build the project.
6. There should be two new `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` variables at the bottom of the .cs file.
7. Save the project and rebuild, two more variables should now be at the bottom.
8. Repeat 5-7 until you're convinced something funny is going on.

What I found out is that if I comment out the `Dock` line in `MainTabPanel`, this doesn't occur.

So ultimately my question is why in the world is this happening?

Comment: What happen if you comment the line `this.ColumnCount = 2;` or give some other number to the `columncount`

Comment: @gmailuser That number determines how many columns are added each build. If I comment out that line, plus the lines below it due to null exceptions, then the grid will have zero columns. I need the grid to always have two columns.

Comment: I mean to say change the value just for debugging purpose. For eg. if you assign 3 columns, same thing happens or not.

Comment: @gmailuser Yes it does, that's what I meant in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false.

Answer (score 0):

How about clear the datagridview each time opening the form?
Form1.DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()